# Emacs/ibuffer: How to switch buffers by using incremental search

Tags: emacs

I'm using ibuffer and finding it very powerful for switching between buffers in Emacs.
There is one thing I can't find how to do - how to search for specific buffer by doing partial incremental search.

Something like dynamic filer?..

I know the feature is available in ido - but I prefer to use one tool for buffer switching (ie in ibuffer).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: count the number of keystrokes you currently use, then compare with using helm or ido.  Remember, you have to do this a lot, so it adds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular incremental search (C-s) in the buffer list, since it's a text buffer.

Comment: It works,but not good enough,especially when you got lots of files with the same names...XD

Comment: @zhkzyth see this: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html

Comment: thanks~~I just find some great stuff to switch buffer easily.  
Like the iswitchb-buffer command, just set  `(iswitchb-mode 1)` on emacs init file,and run `M-x iswitchb-buffer` to use it.  
or use the `helm-mini` command,which is a part of [helm][https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm] porject.I find this one really awesome!!!